# PHP Image Upload (WordPress Custom Plug-in)

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I have a WordPress plug in that I am working on and I seem to have hit a problem. 
I need the user to be able to upload an image, instead I keep getting this problem:

Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/productimages/78.105.162.431328735863.png)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper
>   does not support writeable connections in
>   /home/markpeth/public_html/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/products.php
>   on line 39

---

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/phpowqMlu' to
>   'http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/productimages/78.105.162.431328735863.png'
>   in
>   /home/markpeth/public_html/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/products.php
>   on line 39 There was an error uploading the file, please try again! 
>   You have successfully added test_title to your products list

---

The directory definitely exists and I even changed the CHMOD to 777 for a test.

The products.php file looks like this:

```
 <?
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
 {
global $wpdb;

$product_title = $_POST['title'];
$product_url = $_POST['url'];
$product_btn_text = $_POST['btn_text'];

// CREATE UNIQUE NAME FOR IMAGE
$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time = time();
$new_name = $remote_addr;
$new_name .= $time;


// IMAGE UPLOAD

$upload_dir = "http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/productimages/"; 

if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
        echo "<br /> Directory exists and is fine.... <br />";
}
else {
        echo "Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist. <br />";
}

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
$extension = explode(".", $uploadedfile);
$extensiontype = $extension['1'];

$target_path = $upload_dir;
$target_path = $target_path .$new_name .'.'.$extensiontype; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded <br />";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";

}

$product_img = $new_name.'.'.$extensiontype;

//ADD TO DATABASE
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_rec_amazon_product (product_title, product_url,    product_img, product_btn_text) VALUES ('$product_title', '$product_url','$product_img','$product_btn_text')");
echo "You have successfully added "  .$product_title.   " to your products list";

} else { ?>

 <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" bordercolor="none" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Product Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="product title" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Url</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="url" value="product url" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Button text</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="btn_text" value="Get your copy" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
    <input type="file" name="image_file" />



    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

 <?php }?>
```

The information gets added to the databse, its just the image upload that does not seem to be working.

Has anyone got any ideas? thank you all in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @thenetimp said!

The destination of move_uploaded_file cannot be a URL. But instead has to be a path on the local file system.

$upload_dir has to point to a local path like

```
windows: c:/some/path
unix: /some/path
```

Comment: Sorry yeh, I used this: /home/markpeth/public_html/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/ and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your upload dir is URL  That is your problem.  It needs to be a local filesystem path

Also,  you have an if conditional to check if you can write the file, but do nothing but spit out a text response.  You should be doing your work in there, instead it's below the if conditional.  That's bad.  YOu should do this.

```
if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    echo "<br /> Directory exists and is fine.... <br />";
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
    $extension = explode(".", $uploadedfile);
    $extensiontype = $extension['1'];

    $target_path = $upload_dir;
    $target_path = $target_path .$new_name .'.'.$extensiontype; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded <br />";
            $product_img = $new_name.'.'.$extensiontype;

            //ADD TO DATABASE
            $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_rec_amazon_product (product_title, product_url,    product_img, product_btn_text) VALUES ('$product_title', '$product_url','$product_img','$product_btn_text')");
            echo "You have successfully added "  .$product_title.   " to your products list";

    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";

    }


}
else {
    echo "Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist. <br />";
}
```

Comment: http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/ios/wp-content/plugins/rap/includes/productimages/ is NOT a local path. It is a URL that can be visited in the browser.  You need the file system path /home/username/public_html/uploads would be a possible example.  @user914330 has pointed out you can use wp_upload() to get the directory path for the wordpress uploads directory.

Answer (score 1):

wp_upload_dir()

will return the local file path of your upload directory in WordPress.

in your script, put : $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
instead of the static string you have there.